# R - running out of RAM with write.table in a loop

Tags: r, loops, ram, write.table

Everyday I'm parsing around 700 MB from web in one seconds intervals with VB script. Procedure creates around 13,000 files daily.

With R I'm trying to put those files into the databases. In order to achieve that I created *for loop* that goes through all the files I've downloaded and writes them into databases that are stored *directory*.

At each iteration I have the follwing code:

```
rm(list=c('var1', 'var2'))
unlink(file)
gc()
```

which I hoped to solve the problem. It didn't.

Within the main loop I have inner loop to save the files after being read.

```
for (i in seq_along(listofallfiles)) {
    (here goes code to parse data out of files and store them in var1, var2, etc. -)
      file = paste(path,"\\",l[i], sep="")
      txt  = readLines(file,skipNul = TRUE)

      html      = htmlTreeParse(txt, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

      name      = xpathSApply(html, "//td/div/span[starts-with(@class, 'name')]", xmlValue)

(then goes many more var2, var3 that are based on xpathSapply)


           for (j in seq_along(name)) {

                final_file = paste(direction,"\\", name[j], ".csv", sep="")

                if (file.exists(final_file)) {
                     write.table(t(as.matrix(temp[j,])), file=final_file, row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE, col.names = FALSE)   
                } else {
                     file.create(final_file, showWarnings = FALSE)
                      write.table(t(as.matrix(temp[j,])), file=final_file, row.names = FALSE, append=TRUE)
                }
           }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM**

When I open Task Manager I see that memory usage of RStudio is around 90% after reading merely 50% of the files from one day. That means I won't be able to create even one database for one day. RAM usage at 55% is around 4,2GB.

It's even stranger because the size of the databases created in the *directory* is around 40MB only!

**QUESTION**

Is there any way to build such a database with R? 
I've chosen write.table but it can be any function that gives me an output which can store in iterative manner (so the function that can append data to existing file).

If not in R - in what programming language then?

**EDIT**

*Database* - for now it's planned as flat file (csv). This was confusing. The goal is to store data in anyway that is possible and efficient for reading in R again (not using too much RAM)

*file* - these are HTML files, that's why I'm using xpathSApply. One file is roughly 28KB.

**SOLUTION**

My solution to the problem was creation of outer loop that reads data in chunks. After each iteration of the loop I put

```
 .rs.restartR()
```

which solved the problem.

Comment: (a) No need for `rm`. (b) No need for `file.create`. (c) `gc` probably doesn’t help here either, although there are situations where R fails to reclaim memory otherwise. (d) Your code doesn’t explain the memory consumption. The code you’ve elided must be causing that.

Comment: I think the problem might rather be in the code you don't show us. I noticed R hogs a lot of memory when reading in many files at a time. What I have done when I faced a similar problem was to create several smaller csv files and then merging them afterwards.

Comment: Thank you guys. I added code that goes within inner loop - it's simply readLines of each file within path, then many variables (around 30) are declared by xpathSApply.

Comment: *Databases* - are you using this term correctly? I am seeing flatfile CSVs output no RDMS calls. Also, what format are the *files*? HTML tables? XML files? Sample data can help. I would break this into two loops instead of nested.

Comment: In my experience, the XML package can be rather iffy when it comes to memory management. Try using the xml2 package instead.